How can I get the effect of "git mv" when using drag and drop with VS Code workspace explorer?
If you move a file to a new folder using git mv it will show it like this on git status:
renamed:    cardObjectMock.ts -> object-mocks/cardObjectMock.ts

however, if you do the same through VS Code's workspace explorer, it does:
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    cardObjectMock.ts

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        object-mocks/

The benefit of doing it through VS Code is that imports will get automatically updated.
How can I drag and drop but get the benefit of git mv?

I think drag and drop is like mv. git mv is like mv + git add.

Thank you @ElpieKay but if I do git mv I see in source control the moved file with an R of renamed, whereas if I do it with drag and drop I see it as a D of deletion and an U of untracked. Maybe a vscode plugin like gitlens is interfering?

No, you simply moved the file without telling git about it.

Git does not care whether you used git mv or not. Just add the untracked file and make sure the removal at the old location is also known by Git (I don't know how you do that in VS Code). Then you have the effect of git mv.

thank you @j6t but I think that if I did that, I would love the previous git history of the file. If it is removed and readded, I think that for git it is considered to be a brand new file and I'd like to avoid that.

@danivicario Absolutely not. It is exactly the same. git mv is also just an add and a remove. No strings attached, no hidden info. You lose nothing. And you gain nothing by using git mv.

@danivicario To view the history of a renamed file, you can use git log --follow -- $current_path. It also prints the history before renaming.

@j6t you were right! when you do the rename, both via git mv or with vscode, you don't lose the history as you said, but only after you have run a new git add and a new git commit. Only then I see the git history of that file in gitlens inspect.
Thank you very much indeed for all your responses guys! very useful
